# Fortify option with NDK

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk, clang, fortify

I tried to compile a simple function with Android Studio and current NDK / CLang.
I always get an error with strcpy.

```
char[5] TVolumeDescriptor::StandardIdentifier
strcpy(cTermVolumeDesc.StandardIdentifier, "CD001");
```

The error I got is `error: 'strcpy' called with string bigger than buffer`
I tried the same with gcc native c++ build and no error comes up.

My Gradle CMake is:

```
cmake {
   arguments '-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-29','-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang',
'DANDROID_ARM_NEON=TRUE','-DANDROID_STL=c++_static'
   cFlags '-O3', '-fsigned-char'
   cppFlags '-std=c++11', '-fsigned-char', '-fPIC'
}
```

Anybody can give me a hint who is wrong? Clang and Fortify or I?

Comment: strcpy _"Copies the C string pointed by source into the array pointed by destination, **including the terminating null character** (and stopping at that point)."_ So that's 6 chars in total.

Answer (score 0):

C strings have a terminating null character, and `strcpy` copies this character as well, so you're actually trying to copy 6 characters into an array that has a capacity of 5 characters.

You can now either:

1. Change your array so that it has room for 6 chars instead of 5.
2. If the array must be exactly 5 chars long and it doesn't matter if it contains a valid C string (i.e. whether there's a null terminator), then you can exchange `strcpy` for something like `strncpy`: `strncpy(cTermVolumeDesc.StandardIdentifier, "CD001", sizeof(cTermVolumeDesc.StandardIdentifier));`. You may want to do this even if you go for option 1, simply to reduce the risk for bugs like these.